# minmum length validation rule depending on another attribute not working in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

```
class AddRoomRequest extends Request {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:2|max:1000',
            'base_occupancy' => 'required|integer|min:0|max:100',
            'max_occupancy' => 'required|integer|min:0|max:100'
        ];
    }

}
```

Above code shows my request class this validation rule is not working, even if i give base occupancy as 2 and max occupancy as 10, this will still show **error**.

> bothvalues are int(11) in database.

Comment: Try with size:2|size:1000

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a custom validation rule by extending the validation class. I can't test this right now, but try this:

```
Validator::extend('greater_than', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    if (isset($parameters[0])) {
        return intval($value) > intval($parameter[0]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your `max_occupancy` rule would then be:

```
'max_occupancy' => 'required|integer|max:100|greater_than:base_occupancy'
```

Comment: the "$parameters" array returning is :   array:1 [▼
  0 => "base_occupancy"
].   so i am  not getting the value of base_occupancy to check "greater_than" condition.